# Outer joining on two columns and skipping Null in T-SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have to `left outer join` on either column A or B and not on `NULL`

So I'm not sure how I would do this.

If it was just the case of skipping `NULL` I could put a `where` clause on the join `select` but as I need both columns that doesn't work.

**Here is a example of what I'm trying to accomplish:**

```
**MainTable**

| Mobile |  Email  | MoreInfo |
|  1234  |         |    a     |
|  1234  |         |    b     |
|        | c@c.com |    c     |
|  9999  |         |    d     |
|  4321  |         |    e     |
|        | a@a.com |    f     |

**ReferenceTable**

| Mobile |  Email  | Id |
|  1234  |         | 1  |
|  4321  |         | 2  |
|        | a@a.com | 3  |
|        | b@b.com | 4  |

SELECT mt.MoreInfo, rt.Id
FROM MainTable mt
LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable rt ON mt.Mobile = rt.Mobile OR mt.Email = rt.Email
```

**What I want to get out of this is:**

```
| MoreInfo |  Id  |
|    a     |   1  |
|    b     |   1  |
|    c     | NULL |
|    d     | NULL |
|    e     |   2  |
|    f     |   3  |
```

But will definitely get a value in C and D as well as their null or empty values in email or mobile will match with such values in the reference table.

**EDIT**

I want to note that **ReferenceTable** will always have either `Mobile` or `Email` but never both. As given in the example however the **MainTable** might not have a match in **ReferenceTable** hence the outer join.

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aaf9e/1)

Comment: can you clarify what kind of value do you want instead of Null in the ID column?

Comment: Comparing null to null gives false/unknown so tables will not be joined by nulls. Fiddle shows result same as one you want to get so where is the problem?

Comment: @mucio Yes it's actually a string (varchar), didn't think that would be relevant.

Comment: @JarekBielicki OK I thought that didn't work that way on outer joins, but there are also cases of empty string instead of null :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified version of Dimt answer with protection from comparing empty string

```
SELECT mt.MoreInfo, rt.Id
    FROM MainTable mt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable rt 
    ON (mt.Mobile = rt.Mobile AND coalesce(rt.Mobile, '')<>'') 
       OR (mt.Email = rt.Email AND coalesce(rt.Email, '')<>'')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware about null to null comparison result. Learn something new everyday :) +1

Answer (score 1):

What's about putting additional condition for eliminating null or empty values such as

```
   SELECT mt.MoreInfo, rt.Id
    FROM MainTable mt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceTable rt 
    ON (mt.Mobile = rt.Mobile AND rt.Mobile IS NOT NULL) OR (mt.Email = rt.Email AND rt.Email IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Yes this works except that it needed empty string guard as well that I forgot to mention. Its so simple, why didn't I see it :(